Is this a factory pattern or a strategy pattern?
public interface ResultProvider {
    public Type getType(Type type);

    public List<DTO> search(SearchOption searchOption);
}

@Component
public class Test1ResultProvider {
    public Type getType() {
        return Enum.type;
    }

    public List<DTO> search(SearchOption searchOption) {
        repository.find(searchOption);
    }
}

@Component
public class Test2ResultProvider {
    public Type getType() {
        return Enum.type2;
    }

    public List<DTO> search(SearchOption searchOption) {
        repository.find(searchOption);
    }
}

@Service
public class ResultService {

    private final List<ResultProvider> resultProviders;

    public List<DTO> find(SearchOption searchOption) {
        return resultProviders.stream()
                .filter(provider -> provider.getType() == searchOption.getType())
                .findFirst()
                .map(provider -> provider.search(searchOption.getType()))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException());
    }
}

Should it be viewed as a strategic pattern because the behavior of the object changes depending on the conditions? Or should I look at it as a factory pattern because I return different objects depending on the conditions? Or maybe both? If you know this answer, please reply.
I think it's a strategy pattern, but I wondered if it was a strategy pattern.

did you forgot the implements ResultProvider in the class declarations?

This is a leading question. It presumes a design pattern exists in some code and requests agreement with that presumption. As with most leading questions about design patterns, the answer here is none-of-the-above. Most code is not a pattern (nor should it be). It is just code.

You aren't wrong, it's a Strategy pattern.
Strategy: ResultProvider interface
Concrete Strategy: Test1ResultProvider and Test2ResultProvider
Context: ResultService
Client: The code that interacts to ResultService.
Here is a version for Abstract Factory pattern (not a factory method becasue we need to create a familly of object).
public interface ResultProvider {
    Type getType();

    List<DTO> search(SearchOption searchOption);
}

public class Test1ResultProvider implements ResultProvider {
    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return Enum.type;
    }

    @Override
    public List<DTO> search(SearchOption searchOption) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class Test2ResultProvider implements ResultProvider {
    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return Enum.type2;
    }

    @Override
    public List<DTO> search(SearchOption searchOption) {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public interface ResultProviderFactory {
    ResultProvider create();
}

@Component("type")
public class Test1ResultProviderFactory implements ResultProviderFactory {
    @Override
    public ResultProvider create() {
        return new Test1ResultProvider();
    }
}

@Component("type2")
public class Test2ResultProviderFactory implements ResultProviderFactory {
    @Override
    public ResultProvider create() {
        return new Test2ResultProvider();
    }
}

@Service
public class ResultService {

    private final Map<String, ResultProviderFactory> factoryMap;

    public ResultService(Map<String, ResultProviderFactory> factories) {
        factoryMap = factories;
    }

    public List<DTO> find(SearchOption searchOption) {
        ResultProviderFactory factory = factoryMap.get(searchOption.getType().name());
        if (factory != null) {
            ResultProvider provider = factory.create();
            return provider.search(searchOption);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type: " + searchOption.getType());
        }
    }
}

